# Moving from a view controller to a tab bar controller when using storyboards ioS5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitabbarcontroller

I created a tab bar controller in a story board which is working perfect. Now i need to move from a view controller to this tab bar controller. I do not have a separate class for the tab bar controller. However I tried creating a class for this tab bar controller but when i call it/initialise it, it just gives a new tab bar instead of whats on the storyboard. Ive been stuck with this for a while now so any help would be appreciated. So application works this way. viewcontroller1 -> viewcontroller2 -> tabbarcontroller (which has a table view and a map view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want to do is assign an identifier to the TabBarController in the Storyboard, in the Attributes Inspector, and then use that to programmatically instantiate the controller using this code:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarIdentifer"];
```

Comment: Yes i did exactly that. However now what I am currently doing is presenting it modally. Or i could add it as subView. But that would just be a child view. I want this to be parent view. How would i do that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Can you clarify a bit? I think usually UITabBarController's are the parent view, so presenting it modally is the way to go. To do that just modify your segue to modal instead of push.

Comment: Okay so what ive done is right? FOr instance i used presentmodalviewcontroller to present the tab bars. I thought when presenting something modally it becomes the child? If it doesnt then ive done it right so dont have to change it. Let me know

Comment: Yes, presenting it modally is OK. I think issues come up if you try to push it to a navigation stack. By the way, you can present it modally using segues so you don't have to do "presentModalViewController" in the code, if you want.

Comment: Oh yes ive been going over those for the past few days. However I want it to move after a certain functionality in the code has been achieved. If in a case like this i have to explicitly use presentmodalviewcontroller right? or can i do this via the storyboard?

Comment: You can have segues from multiple places to the same controller, though if you want the same instance that won't work.